# How to add a logical AND to a combination of logical ORs using filter and str_detect?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have the following example dataframe "df" with the variable "Text" containing text:

```
df:
    Text
1   I like blue shoes.
2   Black is great!
3   Pink and grey books.
4   I don't like grey trousers.
5   Yellow is my favorite colour
6   No more green!
7   Cars are red.
8   I have a pink bike
```

I use the following code to filter every case which contains at least one of the listed words, which works perfectly fine:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
library(stringi)
library(stringr)

filter <- c("blue","green","yellow","red")
df2 <-
  df %>%
  filter(str_detect(tolower(df$Text), paste(filter, collapse = "|")))

df2:
    Text
1   I like blue shoes.
5   Yellow is my favorite colour
6   No mor green!
7   Cars are red.
```

As an additional condition, I now want to add the combination of "pink" and "grey", filtering for at least one of the listed words above OR the combination. The dataframe I want to have looks like that:

```
df2:
    Text
1   I like blue shoes.
3   Pink and grey books.
5   Yellow is my favorite colour
6   No mor green!
7   Cars are red.
```

Do you have any idea how I can get there?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide minimal, reproducible, representative example(s) with your questions. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `&` operator to combine `filter` operations ( there is also the `|` OR operator).

```
> f1
[1] "blue"   "green"  "yellow" "red"   

> f2
[1] "pink" "grey"

> df
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Text1       Text2
  <chr>       <chr>
1 Yellow      This 
2 red         That 
3 Purple grey The  
4 green pink  other

> filter(df,  str_detect(Text1, paste0(f1, collapse = "|")))

   # A tibble: 2 x 2
   Text1      Text2
   <chr>      <chr>
  1 red        That 
  2 green pink other

> filter(df,  
str_detect(Text1, paste0(f1, collapse = "|")) & 
str_detect(Text1, paste0(f2, collapse = "|")))

  # A tibble: 1 x 2
  Text1      Text2
  <chr>      <chr>
1 green pink other
```

Note the second requires both operations.

### EDIT ADDRESSING THE COMMENT

```
> filter(df,  
    str_detect(Text1, paste0(f1, collapse = "|")) | 
    (str_detect(Text1, "pink") & str_detect(Text1, "grey")))
```

You can still use & or | operators together with brackets to get the logical combinations you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, what I need is not "f1 AND f2" but more "blue OR green OR yellow OR red OR (pink AND grey)", if that makes sense. I've added a more detailed description of my problem in the original question.